# node js forever server automatically restart without any crash

Tags: javascript

node.js for every server restart automatically restarted:

> error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGSEGV
>   error: Script restart attempt #2

How to solve this error?

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: segmentation fault error how to solve in node js